# How to execute GRANT commands from shell?

Tags: postgresql, psql

I can restore a whole db using shell commands like

```
sudo -u postgres psql -c "DROP DATABASE mynewdbname with (FORCE);"
sudo -u postgres psql -c "CREATE DATABASE mynewdbname;"
sudo -u postgres pg_restore -d mynewdbname /home/user/restore_20230824.sql -v
```

Than I need to execute some grants. Actually I am executing these manually, from shell, every single time

```
sudo -u postgres psql

mynewdbname 

GRANT ALL ON schema name_of_schema TO application_user_name;
GRANT ALL ON ALL TABLES IN schema name_of_schema TO application_user_name;
```

and a lot of others

I tried to execute command from normal shell user but they failed

```
sudo -u postgres psql -c "GRANT ALL ON schema name_of_schema TO application_user_name;"

ERROR:  schema "name_of_schema " does not exist
```

But schema `name_of_schema` exists, I think it's because i've not selected the db. So I tried

```
sudo -u postgres psql -c "\c mynewdbname; GRANT ALL ON schema name_of_schema TO application_user_name;"
```

But it fails with a cryptic error

```
\connect: invalid integer value "ON" for connection option "port"
```

Briefly: **how can I execute command against a postgres db from shell?**

> If usefull, I'm working under a Debian 12. I've full access to it, but I'd like to execute all commands from normal user because these commands must occasionally executed from not-so-intelligent users [monkeys co-workers]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like the [`psql` documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-psql.html#APP-PSQL-OPTION-COMMAND) describes:

> `-c command`
> `--command=command`
>
> Specifies that psql is to execute the given command string, `command`. [...]
>
> `command` must be either a command string that is completely parsable by the server (i.e., it contains no psql-specific features), or a single backslash command. Thus you cannot mix SQL and psql meta-commands within a `-c` option. To achieve that, you could use repeated `-c` options or pipe the string into psql, for example:
>
> ```bash
> psql -c '\x' -c 'SELECT * FROM foo;'
> ```

But the best solution is to avoid the backslash command at all and connect to the correct database right away:

```bash
sudo -u postgres psql -d mynewdbname -c "GRANT ALL ON schema name_of_schema TO application_user_name"
```

Answer (score 0):

I add my 2 cents

I can execute a whole .sql file against a pc, from shell doing

```
sudo -u postgres psql -d <name_of_db> -f /path/to/file_to_execute.sql
```